# Access 2013 Query Criteria in multiple column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table as below

```
Block   SAP SAG BAP BAG 
600400  1   3        
600401          1   3 
600402              
600403  1   4   2   4 
600404          1   3 
600405          3   4 
600406  1   3        
600407  1   2   3   5
600408  4   5        
600409                
600410  1   3   1   3
```

I want the answer like this

```
Block   SAP SAG BAP BAG
600400  1   3       
600401          1   3
600404          1   3
600406  1   3       
600410  1   3   1   3
```

My intension is to filter 1 and 3 in all the four columns using Query !

I used Criteria and OR tabs in query design, but I can't generate the result as I want

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What about nulls? `SAP`,`SAG`,`BAP`, and `BAG` can be 1, 3 or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy, I think this is what you need.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE (SAP = "1" And SAG = "3") OR  (BAP = "1" and BAG = "3");
```

Same in design view:
[image]